# Public Key Encryption

Tags: public-key-encryption

I just wanted to make sure I am on the right track

1. Sender generates private key, encrypts message
2. Sender requests receivers public key
3. "Secret" is then encrypted with this public key
4. Data sent to receiver for decryption

I assume logically speaking the "Secret" can only be encrypted with the receivers public key, although is the encrypted secret attached to the encrypted file / document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

p1. Sender generates session symmetric key.

p3. session key is encrypted using this public key.

Yes, the encrypted secret is attached to the encrypted file. There's no risk in this as this is a session (one-time) key.

Comment: Very confused, there is so much crap on the internet, some articles contradict each other :S

Comment: @Den I always recommend this book as a basic reading on public key crypto: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0072254947?ie=UTF8&tag=eldocorp-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=0072254947

Comment: It is not so complicated. You have to think about what it means when you encrypt something. You want, that only one person can read it. So you have to use the public key of that person, because everything encrypted with the public key can only decrypted with the matching private key. Encryption is always done with public keys. Private keys are used for signing by the sender and decryption by the receiver.

Comment: @ceving I suggest that you read how PKI works on large data blocks. See my reference to the book above.

Comment: @Eugene: The question was about public key encryption and not about making public key encryption faster by using additional symmetric encryption. DES is about 100 times faster than RSA, and because of that everybody uses symmetric encryption to speed up public key encryption. But that is another question and has nothing to do with the the way public key encryptions works.

Comment: @ceving guess you've read too much abstract theory. In practice nobody uses plain public-key encryption on large amounts of data just because it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 2):

Public key encryption: An easy way to visualize this is as follows:

I send someone an unlocked box that they can put stuff in. Then they close it and it locks. They can ship me the box and I have the only key that will open the lock.

The locked box is the public key encryption; the key is my private key.

Symmetric key encryption works like this:

We buy a padlock at Home Depot and it comes with two keys. You take one and move to Boston; I take one and move to San Jose. We can padlock our box and ship it back and forth, only we have the keys.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sender generates **session symmetric key**.

   - Symmetric meaning both parties will use the same key.
2. Sender encrypts **data** with **session key**.
3. Sender requests receivers **public key**.
4. Receiver sends **public key** while keeping the matching **private key** secret.
5. **Session key** is encrypted using receivers **pubic key**.

   - Now only the receivers **private key** can decrypt the **session key**.
6. Encrypted **Data** and encrypted **session key** are sent to receiver.
7. Receiver decrypts senders **session key** using receivers secret **private key**.
8. Receiver decrypts **data** using decrypted **session key**.

Sticking with John Browne's metaphor:

1. I lock a document in a box with a key.
2. I ask a friend to send me a box to which only they have a key too.
3. I place a copy of my document-box-key in my friends box and lock it.
4. I send the document box and my friends box (which contains the key to the document box) to my friend.
5. My friend opens their box with their secret key, and retrieves the document-box-key from inside.
6. My friend then uses that key to open the document box.